# How to create a time table component in GWT

Tags: gwt

I'm new to GWT and I would like to create a time table like component.
sample image is given below,

[image]

Can someone help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far? did you check the FlexTable widget? or the DataGrid / CellTable widgets?

Comment: I haven't started to create the component; I think this is a combination of dataGrid and multi selection on that grid. I'm seeking the best component we have